# In my Dell R310 server, i would like to install CentOS, but for RAID1 what special care i need?

Tags: linux, fedora, centos, raid

I have my Dell R310 server to install CentOS latest version, it has 2 hot plug disk drive, about 250GB of each. 
- But i need to install RAID1 on it.

My question is for RAID1 installation with CentOS is there any special ISO? Or i can use the regular one? Anyone can recommend some working document/screenshot/video links, for RAID1 installation only (i do not want to go with RAID0 or RAID5 etc tutorial, makes more confuse, i decided to only use RAID1 and learn from it)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, There is no special ISO for that, its the same one. If you have Hardware RAID use it to make one drive and follow by booting as regular CentOS installation.

Comment: "If you have Hardware RAID use it to make one drive" could you explain what does mean "use it to make one drive". Should i do it with special util or just using special bios settings? Thx

Comment: The RAID controller usually has its own BIOS that you can get into on bootup.  If that's what you mean by "special bios settings" then yes, you don't need a special utility (if by that you mean something you run within an OS.)